# Validation Elasticsearch mapping application

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm writing an indexer in Java for Elasticsearch, and I'm very afraid of pushing documents to index that doesn't have proper mapping, thus rendering it useless for my future queries.

Is there any method in official java client I can use so I can verify my create an index / put mapping requests not only landed in Elasticsearch cluster, but also were successfully applied, and cluster now is in a consistent state?

The thing I'm actually searching for is to make those requests synchronous rather than asynchronous, but I can't find anything like this in documentation (and I wonder if this is possible within Elasticsearch architecture).

Comment: `The thing i'm actually searching for is to make those requests synchronous rather than asynchronous` .Can you elaborate this line with respect to rest of the question?

Comment: @MayurBuragohain i was always bad at definitions. At current point, two operations - mapping application and scan-and-scroll inside my managing application - are not guaranteed to execute linearly, because mapping application, as far as i understand, is asynchronous operation and has a chance to complete after i push first document to ES. So i need to have some kind of guarantee that when i start scan-and-scroll, index is ready to accept documents, i guess it would be simply called 'to linearize those two operations'.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the refresh API, which is synchronous, after setting your mapping.

Maybe somebody else with more experience can chime in with whether it's actually necessary or not.